# $.ajax() error to return value [object HTMLInputElement]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Every process of receiving data from the input-field and send to data base is picking up normally. When i try to get data after send to data base i'm getting a error `[object HTMLInputElement]`.

[image]

When i change the return mode from `text` to `html` it returns the data effectively this data comes together with input-field you can check this on print-screen below;

[image: The arrows represent of border-bottom of input-field]

The arrows in red represent of border-bottom of input-field.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#publish-sell').click(function () {
            var payload = {
                nameClient: $('#nameClient').val(),
                nameFantasySell: $('#nameFantasySell').val(),
                addresOfClientSell: $('#addresOfClientSell').val(),
                annotations: $('#annotations').val(),
                neighborhood: $('#neighborhood').val(),
                cep: $('#cep').val(),
                phoneLandline: $('#phoneLandline').val(),
                cellphone: $('#cellphone').val(),
                autocompleteBusinessReseller: $('#autocompleteBusinessReseller').val(),
                amountProduct: $('#amountProduct').val(),
                productSoldSell: $('#productSoldSell').val(),
                producFinalPrice: $('#producFinalPrice').val(),
                registeredDaySell: $('#registeredDaySell').val()
            };
            $.ajax({
                url: "/product/sell-sucess",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json",
                processData: false,
                data: JSON.stringify(payload),
                complete: function (data) {
                  $("#printReceipt").click(function () {
                    $("#nameClientReciept").html(nameClient);
                  });
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

This my output result.

```
<h2 class="left-align white-text person-name" id="nameClientReciept"></h2>
```

Comment: You're setting `nameClient` which I don't see in your code and it appears to be an `HTMLInputElement` if you want the value `nameClient` of your payload you need to change `nameClient` to `payload.nameClient`,

Comment: That’s not an error; that’s a string representation of an `<input>` element. You didn’t define `nameClient` anywhere, so I assume, it just automatically takes the `<input>` with that ID.

Comment: @Gerardo Thanks for helping!!!! Really my mistake was in effecting in the data output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no variable named `nameClient`, what you've got is a property of an object, i.e. it would be `payload.nameClient`.
However your code indicates that there is an element with that ID

```
nameClient: $('#nameClient').val(),
```

When you just do

```
$("#nameClientReciept").html(nameClient);
```

What you're really doing is

```
$("#nameClientReciept").html(window.nameClient);
```

And that is indeed an element, as elements are added as properties to the global object, based on their name/id.
What you wanted was probably just

```
$("#nameClientReciept").html(data);
```

As a sidenote, you shouldn't put event handlers inside event handlers, like you're doing.

Comment: thanks for your explanation this my error i was not reporting output value